# Cms home page is not calling on front page having 3 columns

Tags: magento

I want to show all my pages in 3 columns, But when i Changed the default cms Home page having 1 column to 3 columns then its content is not showing on front end only 3 columns structure is showing but its product page is not showing not even static data.
if anybody knows this then please help me out
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Home layout setting  is managed from admin>CMS >Page .Please check admin >cms>page find home page and goes to its Design tab ,change here home page design
OR

go to you template folder create folder layout>create local.xml

```
frontend\your package\yourtemplate\layout\local.xml content is

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <default>
            <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            </reference> 
    </default>
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

Comment: Ya i have already done this. I have changed the design to 3 columns but i think that cms page is not calling.....i am writing anything staic in content but it is not showing in Home page.......